# Bind parent window control to usercontrol's property

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a window which has a tabcontrol. Content of one of the tab items is set to a usercontrol. There is a button in my main window whose IsEnabled property needs to be set to a property that is exposed by the usercontrol. I hope to do this the clean way i.e. using binding.

If that is not possible, then I can do it the dirty way by setting the button's IsEnabled property in the usercontrol. I tried some solutions posted on this group to get access to the main window, but I am not able to get it.

Any help with either of the approaches is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to do this in code behind or XAML?

Comment: Preferably XAML, but if that is complicated/impossible, then code behind would do too.

Comment: I think you can make event based solution. Mean when ever your isEnabled property of user control is changed fire manual event on that and on window side coding you register event handler for that and change the value accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by giving the usercontrol a name, here is an example with a checkbox but it stands with usercontrols as well.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Tab1">
                <CheckBox Name="checkBox1">Toggle to toggle button isEnabled</CheckBox>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkBox1}"></Button>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```